# django if any of many to many has filed with value of False

Tags: python, django

Say I have a model of a library and I want to hide some books if either the book is marked as hidden or any of authors is marked as hidden or any of categories is marked as hidden.

```
class Category(CustomModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    ...
    is_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Person(CustomModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    ...
    is_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Book(CustomModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Person, null=False, blank=False)
    translators = models.ManyToManyField(Person, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=False, blank=False)
    ...
    is_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now I tried these queries to exclude all books with either, `is_hidden=True`, `authors__is_hidden=True`, `translators__is_hidden=True`, or `categories__is_hidden=True`:

as this:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(
                is_hidden=False,
                authors__is_hidden=False,
                translators__is_hidden=False,
                categories__is_hidden=False).distinct()
```

and this:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(
                is_hidden=False,
                authors__is_hidden__in=[False],
                translators__is_hidden__in=[False],
                categories__is_hidden__in=[False]).distinct()
```

but I cannot find a way to achieve it. I wish to achieve my goal without a loop since the number of entries can get as high as 80K. How to make the query?

Comment: And what's wrong with your current attempt?

Comment: It does not return correct number of rows.

Comment: Ough. Yes: you're looking for books that have at least one of each of authors, translators and categories, with at least one member of each category having `is_hidden=False`. You'll need to `.exclude(is_hidden=True).exclude(authors__is_hidden=True).exclude(translators__is_hidden=False).exclude(categories__is_hidden=True)` (first can be `filter` instead, `exclude` just for consistency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Q objects, like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

books = Book.objects.filter(
    is_hidden=False
).exclude(
    Q(authors__is_hidden=True) |
    Q(translators__is_hidden=True) |
    Q(categories__is_hidden=True)
).distinct()
```

This might help you to only get books that are not hidden and have no hidden authors, translators, or categories.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) too.

Answer (score -2):

One possible way to achieve your goal is to use the Q() object to construct a complex query with logical operators. For example, you can use the ~ operator to negate a condition, and the | operator to combine multiple conditions with OR logic. Here is an example query that excludes all books that have any hidden attribute:

```
from django.db.models import Q

books = Book.objects.filter(~Q(is_hidden=True) & ~Q(authors__is_hidden=True) | ~Q(translators__is_hidden=True) | ~Q(categories__is_hidden=True)).distinct()[^1^][1][^2^][2]
```

This query will return all books that are not hidden, and do not have any hidden authors, translators, or categories. The distinct() method is used to avoid duplicate results. You can read more about the Q() object and how to use it in the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to use your example. It returned all rows. I will upvote your answer if you can make it actually run.